# Visual studio Angular - the extensions seem to not work on the .html files

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Just installed Visual studio code and angular cli. I also installed some extensions;

- Bracket pair colorizer from coenraad and
- Angular V5 snippets from John Papa

It looks like the bracket colorizer in not working on the .html files;

[image: The component.html file looks like this]

The component.html file looks like this. As you can see, the brackets are not colorized.

[image: The component.ts looks like this]

This is the component.ts file. In this one, everything works fine.

Comment: also the parenthesis HelloWorld**()** should be colorized as well if im not mistaken.

Comment: why? it is not important.

Comment: @Dmitry Grinko yes, not that important. But I suppose, as the project gets even more complicated, this would be pretty helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is known that angular parsing is not complete. The corresponding issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/CoenraadS/BracketPair/issues/79).

Comment: Hmm ok thanks. Do you think a reinstall of Visual studio or angular will fix it?

Comment: You could try it but I do not think it will change something, because it is the problem of the extension not of vscode or angular.